# Lexer: Handling unterminated strings whilst tokenizing

Tags: string, parsing, antlr, lexical-analysis, lexical

I have started writing my own lexer and ended up with a problem with tokenising strings as they have a start (") and an end (") character associated with them.

Does anyone know of a common technique where a lexer can cope and continue lexing with having an unterminated string?
I think ANTLR can do this, is this handled by a ATN in ANTLR?

I can see there being two issues here assuming that strings must terminate on a single line:

1. String termination occurs on a separate line -- therefore warning the user that strings can only be put on a single line.
2. String termination does not occur, then when do you know a valid point to continue is at? Use a heuristic of the next valid token after the new line.

i.e.

```
char *mystring = "my string which is unterminated....
int id = 20;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your language prohibits newlines in string literals, then just terminating the string at the end of the line is likely to be acceptable. It is reasonably unlikely that there will be a declaration or keyword statement on the same line as the string literal (and there is no reason to encourage bad style by trying to compensate for it.)

You might skip a useful close parenthesis:

```
 printf("%s\n, line);
```

but you likely have recovery rules in place which can cope with that.

If string literals can contain newlines -- and there is ample evidence that this feature is often desired -- then recovery is rather more difficult and you might well find that the simplest solution all round is to just throw a syntax error which clearly states where the offending string started.

Comment: I read in another answer somewhere that error handling is much better off thrown to the parser rather than the lexer. What is your opinion on this and how would you pass it on as there is no token here...

Comment: @har: There is certainly an argument for centralizing error handling but lexical errors are always going to be detected in the scanner. I normally just call `yyerror` to report the error; in the case of a bad token (equally applies to bad numbers), there is generally nothing else which needs to be done. You could, of course, return a "bad literal" token, and then produce the error message in the parser with a unit production which turns `BAD_LITERAL` into a `value` (or whatever your base non-terminal is) and signals the error.